# Proguard enable build not working with Gson Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, build.gradle, proguard

Once I enabled proguard i am not unable to convert JSON string in the POJO class with help of gson library, I am getting null value but it's working fine when proguard is disabled

```
Log.d(TAG, "JSON: ${StringUtils.data}")
    try {
       val quickReplyButton = Gson().fromJson(StringUtils.data, QuickReplyButton::class.java)
        Log.e(TAG, "quickReplyButtondata:" +quickReplyButton)
    }
    catch (e: Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

Pojo class

```
package com.mypackage.sdk.data.model
    
    data class QuickReplyButton(
        val nodes: List<Node>,
        val showMessageText: Boolean,
        val transitions: List<Transition>,
        val widgetAction: String,
        val widgetType: String,
        val widgetView: String
    )
    
    data class Node(
        val controls: Controls,
        val id: String
    )
    
    data class Transition(
        val from: String,
        val name: String,
        val to: To,
        val trigger: String
    )
    
    data class Controls(
        val `0`: X0
    )
    
    data class X0(
        val event: Event,
        val id: String,
        val text: List<String>,
        val type: String,
        val values: List<String>
    )
    
    data class Context(
        val border: String,
        val color: String,
        val textColor: String,
        val textStyle: String
    )
    
    data class Event(
        val name: String
    )
    
    data class To(
        val sendMessage: SendMessage
    )
    
    data class SendMessage(
        val displayText: String,
        val nvaaId: String,
        val nvaaType: String,
        val selected: String,
        val selectedText: String,
        val selectedValue: String
    )
```

Progurd rules:

```
 -keep class com.mypackage.sdk.data.model.QuickReplyButton { *; }
-keep class com.mypackage.sdk.data.model.SendMessage { *; }
-keep class com.mypackage.sdk.data.model.To { *; }
-keep class com.mypackage.sdk.data.model.Event { *; }
-keep class com.mypackage.sdk.data.model.Context { *; }
-keep class com.mypackage.sdk.data.model.X0 { *; }
-keep class com.mypackage.sdk.data.model.Controls { *; }
-keep class com.mypackage.sdk.data.model.Transition { *; }
-keep class com.mypackage.sdk.data.model.Node { *; }
-keep class com.mypackage.sdk.** { *; }

-keep class com.mypackage.sdk.ui.** { *; }
-keep class com.mypackage.sdk.Utils.** { *; }
-keep class com.mypackage.sdk.Care.** { *; }
-keep class com.mypackage.sdk.CareApplication.** { *; }

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.**{ *; }



-dontwarn java.lang.reflect.**
-keep class kotlin.** { *; }

-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
```

Comment: Have you verified that the ProGuard config works? For example when you add debug logging for the `QuickReplyButton` fields, obtained with reflection; does it show obfuscated names? Is the value of the `quickReplyButton` variable `null`, or any (or all) of its fields? Could you please include the log output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "SerializedName" annotation to all of properties.

```
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
var data: Data? = null
```